# Ajax form: new reset state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that's submitted via jquery ajax. How can I **set a new reset state** when the form is submitted via ajax?

For example, there's an input in the form with default value "foo" on page load. User changes value to "bar", hits save (jquery sends form data to server via ajax). Now if user makes additional changes and the user hits form reset button, I want it to reset to "bar" not "foo".

Want to capture "reset" state for entire form, not just specific inputs.
Any insight on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `jQuery('form').reset()`? Or just have a `<input type="reset"/>`?

Comment: @putvande The question doesn't seem to be about how to reset the form, but how to alter the default values/state the form would be reset to.

Comment: That resets the value back to original "foo" value, not "bar". Please read the question clearly first.

Comment: Ow alright.. sorry, misread the question. It's late ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="demoInput" value="foo" />
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', 'button[type=submit]', function () {
      // Store the current value as a data attribute
      $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).data('value',$(this).val());
      });
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'button[type=reset]', function () {
      // Restore the store value
      $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).data('value'));
      });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't try it right now, but setting **defaultValue** properties of inputs may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but setting `defaultValue` to `value` after successful submission will make the reset-button work with the new state.

Simple JQuery example:

```
$("form input").each((ix, t) => { t.defaultValue = t.value; });
```